# IBM Thinkpad R40 does not recognize CD-ROM after Windows reinstall

Tags: drivers, thinkpad, optical-drive

My  IBM Thinkpad R 40 does not recognize the CD-ROM after I reinstalled the original Windows XP. (Before the reinstall it worked without problems).

The BIOS says no drivers are installed, but I did not find the drivers online (at least not in a reliable and serious webpage).

Comment: Have you installed the mainboard drivers (maybe the CD-ROM driver is included)? Have you enforced "Search for new hardware"?

Comment: How did you install Windows XP without the cdrom?

Comment: Is it detected in Disk Management?

Comment: I found a long discussion of it here: http://forums.techarena.in/xp-hardware/921224.htm but alas, no solution.

Comment: @Stefan, first the CD rom worked before the reinstall. Second, there is a RO image of the original Operating System in the hard disk, so you don't need the CD rom to get a factory resinstall

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the BIOS to the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the original CD driver for your Thinkpad from [**Lenovo's website**](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-46024.html#cdrom), along with any other drivers that you may wish to update.

If, after you have installed and restarted, the CD drive is still not appearing, have a look at this Microsoft KB article, titled '[**Your CD drive or DVD drive is missing or is not recognized by Windows or other programs**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314060)'.

The webpage hosts a FixIt tool that may resolve your problem.